# Deriving height(time) for a ferris wheel passenger?

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

I'm trying to figure this out algebraically deriving $h(t)$

I know it's a trig function and by trig: $opposite = adjacent * tan(θ)$

The length of the adjacent side and value of θ are related to a component of the velocity which is related to the circumference of the circle I imagine: $v ∝ \frac{2πr}{t} $

This is about all I have so far, and I'm trying to work it out. Not for homework, my homework was about Ferris Wheels but as it turns out figuring this out is more challenging and fun, just I'm stumped still.

Any tips/help?

Comment: Are you just looking for the height as a function of time? If so, why do you need "the velocity which is related to the circumference of the circle"?

Comment: Yeah, I figured I would need to use the velocity in some argument substituted into $adjacent*tan(θ)$.  Maybe I'm just thinking about this wrong, but I assumed time would naturally arise from the velocity of the passenger going around the wheel.

Comment: I like to see people posing themselves questions, but it is not clear what you are asking.  Please review your post and make the question clear.  Is $h(t)$ supposed to be the height of a person on a Ferris Wheel as a function of time?  Are you assuming the rotation speed is constant?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear.  Yes $h(t)$ is the height of the person on the wheel at the independent variable time.  The speed of the wheel is constant but the function must be open to any arbitrary speed.  The passenger is travelling around the wheel at the arbitrary speed.   Say it takes x seconds to go around the wheel from start to finish, I would like to find the height of the passenger at n seconds, or x+n seconds, for any ferris wheel assuming you knew the radius, and the speed at which the outer circumference of the wheel was moving (v).

Comment: Please edit your answer to include your clarifications - no one likes parsing out comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking for the height as a function of time, you indeed want a trigonometric function but not $\tan$ because it varies from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Instead, you want another trigonometric function like $\sin$ or $\cos$ that varies from $-1$ to $1$ which can be mapped to the bottom and top of the ferris wheel.

Let $t = 0$ be the initial time at the bottom of the ferris wheel at height $0$ and $t = 1$ be the time for half a revolution at the top of the ferris wheel at height $2r$ where $r$ is the radius of the ferris wheel. Given $\cos(0) = 1$ and $\cos(\pi) = -1$, these values are mapped to $0$ at $t = 0$ and $2r$ at $t = 1$ respectively:

$$
h(t) = 2r(1 - cos(t\pi)) \\
h(0) = 0 \\
h(1) = 2r \\
$$

Similarly, $\sin$ could be mapped by applying the complement rule:

$$
h(t) = 2r(1 - sin(\pi/2 - t\pi)) \\
h(t) = 2r(1 - sin(\pi/2(1 - 2t))) \\
$$

If you are also looking for the speed at which the outer circumference is moving, you don't really need a trigonometric function. Instead, you can consider the definition of a radian as the length of a corresponding arc of a unit circle. Given $t$ as the unit for half a revolution and $2\pi r$ as the radians for a complete revolution, the distance traveled by the circumference of the ferris wheel as a function of $t$ can be expressed as:

$$
p(t) = t \pi r \\
$$

The speed of the outer circumference can be measured by differentiating $p(t)$ to $p'(t) = \pi r$. Note that the unit is not necessarily per seconds as $t$ was defined arbitrarily based on half a revolution. See the comments for details to change the unit.

Comment: How does the velocity of the passenger around the wheel affect the function?

Comment: The velocity tangent to the ferris wheel will be constant assuming the wheel is rotating at a constant rate. However, the vertical velocity can be measured by differentiating the function $h(t)$ to $h'(t) = 2\pi r \sin(t\pi)$. As can be confirmed intuitively, the velocity is the greatest (going upwards) at $t = 1/2$ when the ferris wheel is at quarter revolution and the velocity is the lowest (going downwards) at $t = 3/2$ when the ferris wheel is at three quarter revolution.

Comment: But the constant rate of the wheel turning would affect the position of the passenger at any time?    I'm trying to make sense of this atm, sorry if I'm missing something here.  It seems like yours is based on the time being 2 seconds per revolution?

Comment: Yes, but I purposefully chose $t$ to be an arbitrary unit of time based on half a revolution. If you wanted a unit based in seconds and you also wanted $60$ seconds for a complete revolution, then you could replace $t\pi$ with $t\pi/30$.